# Ternary operator with map of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

This is the error in a browser I have used ternary operator to sort it but it's still not working.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

My code is:

```
const HomeScreen  = () => {

const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
const { products, loading, error} = productList;
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());        
    
}, [])

return ( 
    loading ? <div>Loading...</div>:
        error ? <div>{error}</div> : 
            <ul className="products">
              {
                products.map(product =>
                <li key={product._id}>
                    <div className="product">
```

Comment: `productList` does not contain the property `products`. Can you `console.log(productList)` and provide the value (console it before the return)?

Comment: Please update the code snippet with full code.. this contains alot of missing brackets.. painful to read and figure out

Answer (score 0):

`products` may not have been loaded at the time you call the map on it, to make sure that `products` is loaded before mapping over it, change `products.map(product =>` to `products && products.length && products.map(product =>`